# python - Synchronizing two QTreeWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I have two QTreeWidget's in a form, one without children, the other with children as depicted in the screenshot below. I want that the right tree be expanded if it is collapsed (and collapsed if it is expanded), each time an item in the left tree is selected.

[image]

I tried to achieve this with the code below, where I connect a handle function to the itemSelectionChanged event of the left list. The problem is that the .collapse() and .expand() methods require a QIndexModel parameter (inherited from QTreeView), but QTreeWidget use a predefined model which I don't know how to access.

Can anyone out there give me hand?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.tree1 = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree2 = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.tree1.header().hide()
        self.tree2.header().hide()
        self.tree1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelected)
        for text in 'A B C D'.split():
            item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree1, [text])
        for text in '1 2 3 4'.split():
            item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree2, [text])
            for text in 'red blue green'.split():
                child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item, [text])
        layout.addWidget(self.tree1)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree2)

    def handleSelected(self):
        if self.tree2.isExpanded():
            self.tree2.collapse()
        else:
            self.tree2.expand()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree-widget items have a [setExpanded](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setExpanded) method and an [isSelected](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#isSelected) method, so all you need to do is iterate over the top-level items and toggle each one:

```
def handleSelected(self):
    for index in range(self.tree1.topLevelItemCount()):
        item1 = self.tree1.topLevelItem(index)
        item2 = self.tree2.topLevelItem(index)
        item2.setExpanded(item1.isSelected())
```